# PHP Loop through nested arrays to find a specific value then get all elements in that array that gets a match

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have the following multi dimensional array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Botline
        [description] => Kwese
        [parent_team_id] => 
        [company_id] => 10554
        [id] => 13482
        [external_id] => 13482
        [extras] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Books Boutique
        [description] => Kwese
        [parent_team_id] => 
        [company_id] => 10554
        [id] => 13483
        [external_id] => 13483
        [extras] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Sij Investments
        [description] => Kwese
        [parent_team_id] => 
        [company_id] => 10554
        [id] => 13484
        [external_id] => 13484
        [extras] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => Steamcard Investments
        [description] => Kwese installations
        [parent_team_id] => 
        [company_id] => 10554
        [id] => 13549
        [external_id] => 13549
        [extras] => 
    )
)
```

I want to be able to loop through the array searching for a nested array which has a 'id' equal to lest say '13484'. After I find that 'id' I want to be able to get all the elements in that array and save them.

The number of nested arrays which might come in the main array are undefined so I can not create a predetermined way of getting the right array which has the matching value. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Curious how was array created? If from a database or XML, solution is very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to loop, just re-index using the `id` and then reference that element.  This assumes that `id` is unique:

```
$array  = array_column($array, null, 'id');
$result = $array[13484];
```

Or if you only need it once:

```
$result = array_column($array, null, 'id')[13484];
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you name your multidimensional array as `$someArrays` and use `$savedArray` for saving the found array

```
$savedArray = array();

foreach ($someArrays as $someArray) {
    if ($someArray['id'] == '13549') {
        $savedArray = $someArray;
        break;
    }
}

print_r($savedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can the according to the id and it's related values

```
$array = [[

        'name' => 'Botline',
        'description' => 'Kwese',
        'parent_team_id' => '',
        'company_id' => '10554',
        'id' => '13482',
        'external_id' => '13482',
        'extras' => ''
]];

$id = [];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $id[$value['id']]=$value;
}
```

after assign to id here,  the output of id as below

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($id);
echo "</pre>";


Array
(
    [13482] => Array
        (
            [name] => Botline
            [description] => Kwese
            [parent_team_id] => 
            [company_id] => 10554
            [id] => 13482
            [external_id] => 13482
            [extras] => 
        )

)
echo "<pre>";
print_r($id['13482']['name']);
echo "</pre>";
```